# How to run batch file at startup (Windows 10)

Tags: boot, windows-10, batch

I am trying to run a batch file with these contents:

```
ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
DisplaySwitch.exe /external
```

I've tried putting a shortcut to it in the startup folder, putting the bat itself in the startup folder, and running it as a task using task scheduler. I also have UAC completely disabled. It runs fine when I run it myself, but it won't run at startup. How can I get to run when I start the computer?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up

Comment: Did you verify whether it really does not run at startup or whether it only fails? Probably the full path to this executable is required before default paths are setup via environment variables, which is then guaranteed on login. Just a guess ;).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue by running the task at logon instead of startup.